# How can i set Policy Url programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I couldn't find anything in documentations about how to add the policy URL to the request when using the dotnetopenid programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the policy URL you're talking about is the privacy policy URL that you can send along with the Simple Registration request.  The property you're looking for is ClaimsRequest.PolicyUrl.  Here's a snippet that would request a nickname and include your privacy policy:

```
IAuthenticationRequest req = rp.CreateRequest(/*...*/);
req.AddExtension(new ClaimsRequest {
    Nickname = DemandLevel.Request,
    PolicyUrl = new Uri("http://yourprivacypolicy"),
});
req.RedirectToProvider();
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I think beside your great dotnetopenid , there should be some usefull documentation or even forum or wiki for that. the google group is seems dead ;/

Comment: There should definitely be better documentation, I agree.  I disagree that the Google Group is dead.  We have some excellent conversations on it -- periodically.